# Ajax.ActionLink Showing The Previous View

Tags: asp.net-ajax

I have a  @Ajax.ActionLink to show a partial view in a . It is OK. But after showing my partialview in a div, i want to put a button to go back to my first view.

My Ajax Link and Div is in index.cshtml

```
     @Ajax.ActionLink("Edit", "ShowOppEdit", "Opp",  new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "OppInfo", HttpMethod = "GET" })

  <div class="row-fluid" id="OppInfo">
    Text info is here
  </div>
```

My Partial View is a basic form. What i want to do is liking a inline editing. First showing the text, when the visitor click the edit button i want to show editform in a partial view. But at this point, i want visitor can click the Back button to go back the previous text version.

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

So you want to navigatie to the previous action of the Opp controller?

If index is your previous action, just use

```
 @Ajax.Actionlink("back", "Index")
```

Comment: No , I just want to back to previous view whatever it is.